# Should microservice have a tiered architecture, presentation, business, persistence and infrastructure for scalability? There are 10 microservices

Tags: cloud, microservices, 3-tier

The benefits of 3-tier architecture has been well documented over time.

- [https://www.ibm.com/topics/three-tier-architecture#:~:text=The%20chief%20benefit%20of%20three,without%20impacting%20the%20other%20tiers](https://www.ibm.com/topics/three-tier-architecture#:%7E:text=The%20chief%20benefit%20of%20three,without%20impacting%20the%20other%20tiers).
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/using-a-three-tier-architecture-model

Enter Microservices and its architecture

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices
- https://www.ibm.com/topics/microservices
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/learn-architect-microservice/index.html#GUID-BDCEFE30-C883-45D5-B2E6-325C241388A5
- https://thenewstack.io/microservices/what-is-microservices-architecture/

Now, applying 3-tier architecture to each service/microservice would give me three applications to be deployed over three servers. If the application has 10 microservices, then there would be 3 x 10 = 30 servers? This does not take UI into consideration. And all this will be hosted in a cloud environment.

Thoughts? comments?

Comment: Why would you think that each microservice would need its own server?